# Is it possible to list breakpoints with trepan2 python debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, trepan

I was initially very impressed by some of the advanced features of the trepan2 debugger.  But it does not appear to have any command to list breakpoints.  That seems like a bizarre oversight.

Does anyone know is there a command to list the breakpoints for the trepan2 debugger.  I have trepan2 v0.8.4

Answer (score 1):

`info break`

Does the trick.

trepan2 is a little sparse on documentation.  When in doubt, for trepan, as for many gdb inspired command line debuggers start with the assumption it has the same command structure as gdb.

I was initially misled as pdb is a bit of an exception to that assumption and varies from gdb convention more than other command line debuggers.

Obviously trepan doesn't have everything gdb has, but to get e.g. all info "subcommands" type the main command i.e.

`info`

And then once you find the subcommand you are interested in (e.g. in this case break)

`help info break`

And finally it *is* documented, although sparsely:

https://python2-trepan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/info/break.html

Comment: Feel free to contribute more documentation. As someone confused by all of this, you are in the best position to help out others.